# Active Admin date filter date format customisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activeadmin

Is there simple way to change the ActiveAdmin date filter display format from the default ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Answer (score 12):

Instead of overwriting the js you can provide extra options to the datepicker like this:

```
 = f.input :my_date, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }
```

Comment: That is a smart answer and so needs upvoting. Thanks.

Comment: Appears to work on `master` but not yet in version `0.6.x`.

Comment: Is there a way to set this once and have it apply to all datepicker inputs?

Comment: Just tried this with 1.0.0.pre5 and when you go to edit a resource the date is missing and you lose the data.  Doesn't appear to work 100% on the latest pre release version.

Answer (score 1):

The way i fixed is is like this:

```
$ ->
  # reset format
  $('.datepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)').each ->
    if $(@).val().length > 0
      p = $(@).val().split('-')
      $(@).val("#{p[2]}-#{p[1]}-#{p[0]}")

  # change format
  $(document).on 'focus', '.datepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)', ->
    $(@).datepicker dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
```

So first reset the value from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd, than set the correct format on the picker.

Hope this helps someone.

This works in ActiveAdmin pre 1 with the just_datetime_picker gem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. I did it with setting options for datetime picker object with js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'D, d M yy' );

});
```

if you do this, input values will look like

```
Wed, 28 Nov 2012
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate here is manual about supported formats

Comment: is there a way to do this w/o js? in rails

Comment: @TMP, what do yo mean ? datetime picker is js ui component, I don't think you can do somethink with js without js

Comment: well then clearly you wouldn't use datepicker...the question doesn't mention anything about js.  I wanted to know if there was another solution that did not use datepicker/js

Comment: @TMP, active_admin date filter does use datepicker. another solution is to create own component and use for instance html5 date input, but I don't think you can change format that way.

Answer (score 0):

For Active Admin filters..

In the Active Admin gem, file: app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/pages/application.js.coffee, you'll see:

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'focus', '.datepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)', ->
    $(@).datepicker dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

You might have to revise the on focus event, for example (file: app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('focus', '.datepicker.hasDatepicker', function() {
    $(this).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm-dd-yy");
  });
});
```

Or perhaps remove the events and re-initialize datepickers, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // remove existing on focus events
  $._data( $(document)[0], 'events').focusin = null;

  // add new datepicker with format
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nathan Bertram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71044/nathan-bertram) has a good solution, but I feel like it needs some exposition based on my experience and the comments of others. It helped me to look at the ActiveAdmin [source](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/b45b1fb05af9a7f6c5e2be94f61cf4a5f60ff3bb/lib/active_admin/inputs/datepicker_input.rb) for this Input as well.

ActiveAdmin does completely render the Datepicker on page load so that formatting has not been applied yet.  This means that the initial value needs to be formatted as a string. Otherwise you may have the wrong format until you click on the input and select a date.

There are 2 solutions that come to mind:

- [`strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)
- [`I18n.l`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

I prefer the **I18n** approach [because it gives you the ability to save formats for reuse](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

the Datepicker widget uses a different [formatting syntax](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) as compared to Ruby/Rails, make sure that you pick a format that is possible in both syntaxes.  Hence the use of both: `mm/dd/yy` for the widget and `%m/%d/%Y` for the initial value

## A revision of Nathan's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609177/7573223):

```rb
f.input :my_date, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" },
        input_html: { value: I18n.l(f.object.my_date, format: "%m/%d/%Y")}
```

In my actual implementation of this I [created my own Input](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs) and applied the format in an abstracted way.

## My Solution: A minor extension of the Datepicker Input

```rb
form do |f|
  # ...
  f.input :my_date, as: :datepicker, format: :admin_short, input_html: { value: f.object.my_date }
  # ...
end
```

`app/inputs/datepicker_input.rb`
I got the idea for this looking at the source for [ActiveAdmin::Inputs::DatepickerInput](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/b45b1fb05af9a7f6c5e2be94f61cf4a5f60ff3bb/lib/active_admin/inputs/datepicker_input.rb)

```rb
class DatepickerInput < ActiveAdmin::Inputs::DatepickerInput
  def input_html_options
    super.tap { |hash| hash[:value] = I18n.l(hash[:value], format: format) }
  end

  private

  def datepicker_options
    super.tap do |hash|
      datepicker_date_format.then do |date_format|
        hash[:datepicker_options][:dateFormat] = date_format if date_format.present?
      end
    end
  end

  def datepicker_date_format
    I18n.t(format, scope: "date.formats.datepicker") # => "mm/dd/yy"
  end

  def format
    # allow for a fallback when a format is not provided
    options.fetch(:format, "m-d-yy") # => :admin_short
  end
end
```

`config/locales/date_time.en.yml`

```yaml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      admin_short: "%m/%d/%Y"
      # datepicker format syntax will not work with I18n, here for reference
      datepicker:
        admin_short: "mm/dd/yy"
```

**JS/JQuery format syntax will not work in formatting with I18n.**

NOTE: I chose to put the JS/Jquery formats in this file so that they can be easily compared with the Ruby/Rails formats and to allow them to be saved in the same way with matching formats sharing the format key.

thats what makes this function work:

```
def datepicker_date_format
  I18n.t(format, scope: "date.formats.datepicker") # => "mm/dd/yy"
end
```