# Change default date formatter in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, activeadmin

In [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) dates are printed in the, supposedly American, format `%B %d, %Y %H:%M`. E.g. `March 19, 2013 13:25`

However, my "default" frontend prints this using the default Rails (ISO) format, `2013-03-07 14:12:31 UTC`, as seen when dropping a `<%= Date.new %>` anywhere in a view.

1. What is defining the format for the ActiveAdmin dates?
2. Where or how can this be changed, if possible, simply following a global Rails wide i18n setting.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

please, ensure you have next   lines in your config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d"
  time:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Also if you want to change Filter default date formats 
Try this [Active Admin date filter date format customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405230/active-admin-date-filter-date-format-customisation/13266522#13266522)

Answer (score 10):

> What is defining the format for the ActiveAdmin dates?

From the *Localize Format For Dates and Times* section of the configuration docs:

> Active Admin sets `:long` as default localize format for dates and times.

Source: [General Configuration - Localize Format For Dates and Times](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/v1.0.0.pre2/docs/1-general-configuration.md#localize-format-for-dates-and-times).

> Where or how can this be changed, if possible, simply following a global Rails wide i18n setting.

From ActiveAdmin [v1.0.0.pre2](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4026) you can override the default `localize_format` configuration to use a different format:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.localize_format = :short
end
```

Alternatively you can update the `:long` format in your locales configuration as suggested by [Fivell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246544/fivell):

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d"
  time:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Ahh.. nice..  so what I did (so it wouldn't mess up the rest of my applicaiton). is I set the config.localize_format = :admin and created and "admin: " entry in my en.yml for date and time.. allow me control over the format in admin separate from the rest of my app.

Comment: locales are not working for `'activeadmin', '2.4.0'`