# How to change how ActiveAdmin displays time (every time)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activeadmin

Since the default time in the database is in utc, I wanted to be able to still display it in the users correct time. To do this I had to take `column :created_at` and change it into this:

```
index do
...
  column :created_at, :sortable => :created_at do |obj|
    obj.created_at.localtime.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M)
  end
...
end
```

Seems pretty easy to do once or twice, but when you need to override every index and show method, the process get's a little taxing.

Is there a way to override how ActiveAdmin displays time without having to override each occurrence?

I know I could create a function or probably use the functions provided for time better, but I'd still have to use it each time I want to display time.  I want to override it without worrying I missed one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found there are two ways to do this:

**1. Javascript**

This is the easier method because it is very short and doesn't involve adding a db field.  It works because it uses the users timezone from their browser.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942865/1197246) answer gives insight on how to do this.

**2. From the Database**

This process can be found in [this railscast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BjDAgNxoVM).

Essentially store a time_zone field in the users table.  Then use an before_filter (although an around_filter might be a better idea) to set the timezone in the controller.

```
before_filter :set_time_zone

private
def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if current_user
end
```

Answer (score 22):

You can target just ActiveAdmin by telling it to always use a particular filter in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` , by adding a line like this:

```
config.before_action :set_admin_timezone
```

(or `config.before_filter :set_admin_timezone` for versions of Rails before Rails 4)

Then in your ApplicationController, you can just define the method set_admin_timezone, and ActiveAdmin will use it. For example:

```
def set_admin_timezone
  Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

You should be able look up the current admin user in that method (in order to get their particular timezone), but I haven't tried that.

Comment: To ensure it's set first: `config.prepend_before_action -> { Time.zone = "Brisbane" }` (also inlined code since it's not used elsewhere).

Comment: For the Rails 5 app I am working on now I needed to use `config.before_action :set_admin_timezone`

Comment: This does not seem like a good solution. This will set the timezone for activeadmin, but it will also set it for other controller actions, but it seems like it does it intermittently. I dropped a debugger in one of my application controller actions, and printed out `Time.zone` and it would intermittently print UTC sometimes, and EST other times.

Comment: @dkniffin Try putting the debugger inside `set_admin_timezone` and see if it is ever getting called from your other controller actions. If it is, then you may be calling it from somewhere else in your application. If it is not, then some other part of your application may be setting the time zone.

Comment: Yes, @dkniffin is correct that this can cause problems - any actions without an explicit Time.zone assignment can have indeterminate timezones as a result of this. The timezone needs to also be torn down at the end of the request. For example see "https://ilikestuffblog.com/2011/02/03/how-to-set-a-time-zone-for-each-request-in-rails/".

Answer (score 4):

So for my understanding, you need two things:

1. Localtime/Timezone

   You can achieve this by set the right timezone of your rails app, the active_admin will pick up that by default. For example, in your rails config file(config/application.rb):

   config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
2. Default time format

   You can refer this [Change default date formatter in active admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501696/change-default-date-formatter-in-active-admin)

Good luck~

Comment: The timezone will be specific to each user, so configuring the timezone like that won't work

Comment: Well, if you are talking about the client time, then `obj.created_at.localtime.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M)` still not work, cause this is still server time, you can display client time using javascript.

Comment: Yeah I'm slowly coming to this realization.  javascript is a good call though, I was about to add a field to the db for it, but that would be unnecessary

Comment: @Zubin datetimes are always stored in UTC regardless of that config option (which just affects how they're displayed by default)

Answer (score 2):

Setting Time.zone in before action is not safe, since consequent requests, processed in the same thread may be affected.
It is safer to use around action. I.e. in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` you'll have:
`config.around_action :set_admin_timezone`
And in ApplicationController you will have

```
  def set_admin_timezone
    Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') { yield }
  end
```

This will return the timezone to normal after the request, and therefore, consequent requests will be not affected.

Comment: This is the correct answer for changing the format of displayed and entered (form input) dates and times in Active admin to eastern time, without changing the way dates are returned (by your api, for example) to also be in eastern time. I believe OP wants to only change the date _format_. For that, you should edit `config/locales/en.yml` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511930/1137752). However, when I searched for how to change AA's timezone (only) this thread always appears at the top of google's search results. Leaving this here for posterity. Thanks, Serhii.