# Display attributes in loca ltime in ActiveAdmin Admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin in a Ruby on Rails application and need to display the **time attributes** `created_by_id` and  `updated_by_id` in **localtime** but I do not know how to write this in the **ActiveAdmin formtastic DSL**.  The following is the current code listing:

```
  show do |channel|
    attributes_table do
      row :created_by_id
      row :updated_by_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set default `time_zone` in your active_admin initializer (`config/initializers/active_admin.rb`) file like this:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
   admin.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

Please refer this link: [How to change how ActiveAdmin displays time (every time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845646/how-to-change-how-activeadmin-displays-time-every-time)

Comment: Hi when i add this line to the config/initializers/active_admin.rb it get a the following undefined method `time_zone=' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x00000006973cd0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: the following link has a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845646/how-to-change-how-activeadmin-displays-time-every-time

Comment: @GurdipeDosanjh Yes I also added same link to my answer. so that, if my code gives error it will help you get it work.